# Angularjs Dynamic Text Fields and multiply two field

Tags: angularjs, dynamicform

Hi I have a Json Like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Furniture & Fixture",
    "choices": [
      {
        "req_goods": "",
        "qty": "10",
        "rate": "",
        "total": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Miscellaneous Property",
    "choices": [
      {
        "req_goods": "",
        "qty": "",
        "rate": "",
        "total": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Office Equipment",
    "choices": [
      {
        "req_goods": "",
        "qty": "",
        "rate": "",
        "total": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

here choices are my dynamic fields user can add as much choices as they want, my add/remove js is like this

```
$scope.addNewChoice = function(id){
        $scope.capital_budgets[id].choices.push({});
    };
    $scope.removeChoice = function(parent_id,id) {      
        $scope.capital_budgets[parent_id].choices.splice(id,1);
      };
```

my html

```
<div ng-repeat="cb in capital_budgets">
  <div><b><% $index+1 %> <% cb.name %></b></div>                  

  <div ng-repeat="choice in cb.choices">    
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.req_goods">                 
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.qty">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.rate">
    <input type="text" ng-model="choice.total">

   <button type="button" ng-hide="$first" ng-click="removeChoice($parent.$index,$index)">-</button>

  </div>
  <button type="button" ng-click="addNewChoice($index)">+</button>

</div>
```

**Now I want to calculate the total(qty*rate) of each added choices whenever they put qty and rate and put it in total field please help**

Comment: You should be doing `{{ }}` and not `<% %>`

Comment: I think you should be able to inititate a variable as a product of `qty` and  `rate` like `ng-init = "calculatedTotal = choice.rate * choice.qty"` and then assign it to `ng-model = "calculatedTotal"` for total

Comment: `ng-init` will only run once when the view is constructed - it will not update when `rate` or `qty` is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to create a method in your controller to do the calculation and then just call it on a change of `qty` or `rate`.

*controller:*

```
$scope.updateTotal = function(choice) {
    if(!choice.qty || !choice.rate) {
        choice.total = 0;
    } else {
        choice.total = choice.qty * choice.rate;
    }
};
```

*html:*

```
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.qty" ng-change="updateTotal(choice)">
<input type="text" ng-model="choice.rate" ng-change="updateTotal(choice)">
```

Comment: thanks i did like this before what i did wrong was $scope.choice.total = choice.qty * choice.rate; instead of choice.total = choice.qty * choice.rate;